# Use general information to create dataset

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, powerbi

I have set up a file where i'm using some fields to create a dataset.
Projectname
From date
To date
Amount

In my excel file i create a table using VBA where each day between the two dates gets the middle value assigned.

For example if I have the following information (normally in a excel table where one field is one column):

```
project:    project1
From date:  2019-01-01
To date:    2019-01-04
Amount:     100

The table would be:

Project    Date         Amount
Project1   2019-01-01   25
Project1   2019-01-02   25
Project1   2019-01-03   25
Project1   2019-01-04   25
```

My problem is that this method is becoming quite slow when there is a lot of projects and a lot of data in the table (finding removing and updating the dates). So i'm wondering if there is a way to make this more efficient.

It is important to be able to use the information in a pivot table so i'm considering using Excels data model but don't really know how to go about it. I was hoping to get som pointers here :)

Comment: Store your table in one array, get 2 `Date` variables with the from date and to date. A third `Date`variable which will hold the date of each row on your table, then loop through your array checking if the date is between the from and to, if so, change the amount. That takes seconds for 100k of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, if I am getting what you mean :)  My data is the same as yours in `J1:K4` and I am dumping the results from `J6` down

```
Sub AddToTable()

Dim rngInspect As Excel.Range
Dim rngDestination As Excel.Range
Dim strProjName As String
Dim dtStartDate As Date
Dim dtEndDate As Date
Dim dblCost As Double
Dim dblCostPerPeriod As Double
Dim lngPeriods As Long
Dim lngCounter As Long

Set rngDestination = Range("j6")

Set rngInspect = Range("j1:k4")

With rngInspect
    strProjName = .Cells(1, 2).Value
    dtStartDate = .Cells(2, 2).Value
    dtEndDate = .Cells(3, 2).Value
    dblCost = .Cells(4, 2).Value
End With

lngPeriods = DateDiff("m", dtStartDate, dtEndDate) + 1

dblCostPerPeriod = dblCost / lngPeriods

For lngCounter = 1 To lngPeriods

    rngDestination.Offset(lngCounter - 1, 0).Value = strProjName
    rngDestination.Offset(lngCounter - 1, 1).Value = DateAdd("m", lngCounter - 1, dtStartDate)
    rngDestination.Offset(lngCounter - 1, 2).Value = dblCostPerPeriod

Next lngCounter

End Sub
```